# Java android simple http get method

Tags: java, android, http, http-get

We are building an Android app to control a little light conneted to a webserver.

The purpose is when we click the button there will be send a simple httpGETrequest to: `http://192.168.2.179/?led1`

We have tried a lot of different ways, and none of them work.

Do you know a simple way to implement this for our project?

```
public void lihtbulp(View v) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.2.179/?led1");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string


        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the entire logcat:

```
02-09 09:31:35.308    3679-3679/com.example.evelien.domotica D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-09 09:31:35.308    3679-3679/com.example.evelien.domotica E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.evelien.domotica, PID: 3679
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:154)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
            at com.example.evelien.domotica.Domotica.lihtbulp(Domotica.java:76)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-09 09:36:35.393    3679-3679/com.example.evelien.domotica I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3679 SIG: 9
```

the code refers to conn.connect();

Comment: Can you show the code you have already? We won't write the code so it may help to show what you have as well as any LogCat output.

Comment: sorry for that, here is the code:

Comment: Any output in logcat

Comment: 02-09 09:31:35.308    3679-3679/com.example.evelien.domotica E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.evelien.domotica, PID: 3679
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

this is the catlog output:
it happens on the line : 
con.connect();

Comment: Can you post the entire logcat? Paste it into your question not in a comment. I am quite confident that you are doing this HTTP call on the main thread which is not allowed in ANDROID. You must execute all web requests in an AsyncTask, a background task of some sort.

Comment: done, sorry for the long time to get all the info int it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run HTTPRequest in main thread of application in simplest case create asynctask and execute HTTP request inside asynctask.
Check this thread: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)